# minecraft wont run on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

I am a d00b at modding and I'm using the Minecraft Mastery book.

when I try to run the unedited minecraft on eclipse, I get this first:

```
[07:09:48] [main/ERROR]: The binary patch set is missing. Either you are in a development environment, or things are not going to work!
[07:09:52] [main/ERROR]: The minecraft jar file:/C:/Users/minecraft/.gradle/caches/minecraft/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.7.2-10.12.2.1147/forgeBin-1.7.2-10.12.2.1147.jar!/net/minecraft/client/ClientBrandRetriever.class appears to be corrupt! There has been CRITICAL TAMPERING WITH MINECRAFT, it is highly unlikely minecraft will work! STOP NOW, get a clean copy and try again!
[07:09:52] [main/ERROR]: FML has been ordered to ignore the invalid or missing minecraft certificate. This is very likely to cause a problem!
[07:09:52] [main/ERROR]: Technical information: ClientBrandRetriever was at jar:file:/C:/Users/minecraft/.gradle/caches/minecraft/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.7.2-10.12.2.1147/forgeBin-1.7.2-10.12.2.1147.jar!/net/minecraft/client/ClientBrandRetriever.class, there were 0 certificates for it
[07:09:52] [main/ERROR]: FML appears to be missing any signature data. This is not a good thing
```

then after 3 more lines of normal, I get this:

```
[07:09:55] [main/ERROR]: Unable to launch
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:134) [launchwrapper-1.9.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.9.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73) ~[lwjgl-2.9.0.jar:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_71]
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66) ~[lwjgl-2.9.0.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95) ~[lwjgl-2.9.0.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112) ~[lwjgl-2.9.0.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.getSystemTime(Minecraft.java:2523) ~[Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:36) ~[Main.class:?]
    ... 6 more
```

I have also added `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;` to the path variable witch now looks like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\PROGRAM FILES\NOKIA\PC CONNECTIVITY SOLUTION\;C:\PROGRAM FILES\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT SHARED\WINDOWS LIVE;C:\Windows\SYSTEM32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WBEM;C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINDOWSPOWERSHELL\V1.0\;C:\PROGRAM FILES\WINDOWS LIVE\SHARED;C:\PROGRAM FILES\IVI FOUNDATION\VISA\WINNT\BIN;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\VXIPNP\WinNT\Bin;C:\Users\Kieran (Admin)\AppData\Local\Smartbar\Application\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\C:\Program Files\Java\jre8;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\
```

I've already tried downgrading java from 1.8 to 0.7, but it just changed the error slightly.
please help :)

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path` Do you have whatever lwjgl is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing native libraries required by lwjgl.

1. Extract `libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl-platform/2.9.1/lwjgl-platform-2.9.1-natives-linux.jar` to some directory in your project. The name might differ. It should have a bunch of `.so` or `.dll` files inside.
2. Left click on it -> "Build Path" -> "Configure Build Path..."
3. Expand "lwjgl-2.9.1.jar"
4. Select "Native library location: (None)"
5. Click "Edit" and set it to directory which you just created.

Answer (score 0):

As the first log states:

```
The minecraft jar file:/C:/Users/minecraft/.gradle/caches/minecraft/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.7.2-10.12.2.1147/forgeBin-1.7.2-10.12.2.1147.jar!/net/minecraft/client/ClientBrandRetriever.class appears to be corrupt! There has been CRITICAL TAMPERING WITH MINECRAFT, it is highly unlikely minecraft will work! STOP NOW, get a clean copy and try again!
```

Did you try reinstalling Minecraft?

Comment: @Hazzdood Maybe try reinstalling Minecraft then?

Comment: oh. my account is called minecraft.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add the [lwjgl.jar](http://www.lwjgl.org/download.php) to your [classpath](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29).